# android custom button

Tags: android, view, uibutton

I need to create some custom buttons as shown in the image below

[image]

what is the best approach to follow?

thanks
Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 0):

That's a hard one. I made a lot of custom views, and the first thing I would thinking of is, made one Button with that above image, and handle onTouch by yourself so you can distinguish which area the user hit. There you can also change the state of the button, like changing the image to a bevel one e.g. when the left button is hit.

Can you imagine this ansatz?

Answer (score 0):

You can place two transparent "invisible" buttons over the top of a background in a LinearView. Like two ImageButtons with a transparent png inside.

It is also possible to make this background animated when buttons are clicked using android animation class.